# Is there a way to check if QLabel pixmap is set to something particular?

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating an Qt application and I have a part where I can drag QLabel's from one frame to another and I need to know which label is dragged but I don't know how to check that. Is there function or method to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are handling drop-actions by overriding the `dropEvent(QDropEvent *)` method in a subclass of some type of QWidget, you can call [QDropEvent::source()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdropevent.html#source) to get a pointer to the widget that the user clicked on to start the drag.  You can then use that pointer to do a lookup in a table/list of pointers of known drag-sources, or use `dynamic_cast<QLabel*>()` on it to try and get a `QLabel` pointer out of it that so that you can call `QLabel` methods on it, or etc.

Note that this technique only works if the drag-operation started in your own application.  It won't work if the drag-operation came from some other application, of course, because in that case the source-widget is not in your program's process space and therefore there is no way to get a pointer to it.

A slightly-more-elegant alternative method would be to have the source-widget add some identifying data to a [QMimeData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html) object, and then call [setMimeData()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#setMimeData) on the [QDrag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html) object before it calls [exec()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#exec) on it.  Then the receiving widget could look at the [QMimeData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html) object returned by [QDropEvent::mimeData()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdropevent.html#mimeData) to retrieve that information.  This is a bit nicer since it will work across process boundaries, and is safer since you don't have unrelated widgets dereferencing pointers to each other or trying to downcast QObject-pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done it with the first part of your answer.